# How to migrate from Windows Live Photogallery to digiKam?

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, digikam

I'm thinking about moving from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu. I have been very happy with the Windows Live Photogallery application for managing my photos. I have a simple folder structure having one folder per year with several subfolders. I also tagged people, locations, descriptions and used the rating system a lot.

Now I am not sure how I could best move these images to Ubuntu *without loosing tags and ratings*. I have read about digiKam and it sounds very promising. But I could not find any information what happens when I import a photo library from a windows system.

**Do I have to do some additional work to migrate from Live Photogallery to digiKam?** I don't want to lose my tags and ratings.

Comment: It depends a lot on where Live Photogallery saves the data. If it uses a sidecar XMP file you should be ok; if it uses data embedded in the photo --- it depends; if it uses a proprietary database you have little chances. Best thing is trying with a test (you can install digiKam in windows I think). And by the way, probably this question is better asked in the digiKam channel directly... http://www.digikam.org/contact

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I think I'll do a dual installation on my computer and just try it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags and Ratings of Windows Live Gallery are imported without a problem into digiKam or Shotwell.

As @Rmano suggested I just tried it with Shotwell and digiKam (running on Ubuntu 12.04). Imported some images and all the tags and ratings were there. :)